# Is there an way to reshape a column to a row, but the row is make by ID column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I'm trying to reshape a dataframe. Making my column to a row, but the first column controls the rows length.

i tried pandas pivot_table to reshape the column.
    Example: Would like it to look.

```
ID  Apex   max    min    angle
1   A1     30.1  -16.9    NA
2   A1     89     NA      NA
3   B1     100   26.3    68.9
```

---

```
ID  Parameter   Simulated
1   Apex            A1
1   max         30.1
1   min        -16.9
2   Apex            A1
2   max         89
3   Apex            B1
3   max         100
3   min         26.3
3   angle           68.9

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
               'Parameter': ['Apex', 'max', 'min', 'Apex ', 'max',               
                            'Apex', 'max', 'min', 'angle'],
                'Simulated': ['A1', 30.1, -16.9, 'A1', 89,      
                            'B1', 100, 26.3, 68.9],
                },
                 index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

pd.pivot_table(df1, index = 'ID', columns ='Parameter', values = 'Simulated')
```

I'm getting this Error - 
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Thank you for what ever help you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df1.pivot(index='ID', columns='Parameter', values='Simulated')
```

Output:

```
Parameter Apex angle   max   min
ID                              
1           A1   NaN  30.1 -16.9
2           A1   NaN    89   NaN
3           B1  68.9   100  26.3
```

`pivot_table` assumes your are going to aggregate values, by default it will use 'mean', since you have strings, in your data to pivot it is causing the error.

Multiple entries:

```
df1.groupby(['ID','Parameter']).first()['Simulated'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Comment: Hello Scott, I did try this but i'm getting error - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape ... Do you have some ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, you have multiple records.  What you need to do is to do an aggregation of your value records, but because some of your value records are strings and some are numbers, you need to define your aggregration.

Comment: @orthoeng2 Look at my added line.

Comment: Thank you Scott this is very interesting line of code. it works great

Comment: @orthoeng2 Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [43]: df1.set_index(['ID', 'Parameter']).unstack()
Out[43]: 
          Simulated                        
Parameter      Apex Apex  angle   max   min
ID                                         
1                A1   NaN   NaN  30.1 -16.9
2               NaN    A1   NaN    89   NaN
3                B1   NaN  68.9   100  26.3
```

Comment: Hello lexual, I tried this but i'm getting a error - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape ... Do you have some ideas?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using.